# How can my bash find binaries if the binary is not in $PATH?

Tags: linux, bash

I got a class VM which uses ubuntu 18.04 as a base. The terminal is bash and I confirmed from

```
echo $0
```

There is a command called elastalert which auto-complete if I just type "elast" and then hit tab. This is pretty normal for any binaries that locates in $PATH.

However, when i do

```
which elastalert
```

It returns no info. I searched the file from root directory

```
$ sudo find -name elastalert 2>null
./backup/elastalert
./elastic_stack/elastalert
```

However, both path above are directories. I check the $PATH, it does not contain the above path

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

Q: What kind of linux mechanism allows me to auto-complete elastalert, but the elastalert does not exist in $PATH?

Update:

```
$type elastalert
elastalert is aliased to `docker run -it --rm --net=bridge --network=labs_esnet --name elastalert --hostname elastalert -v /labs:/labs --link elasticsearch hasecuritysolutions/elastalert:v0.1.31 /usr/local/bin/elastalert'
```

There are some Qs on why sudo is needed. As you can see below, the files are in directories only accessible to root.

```
$ sudo find -type f -name elastalert 2>/dev/null
[sudo] password for student: 
./var/lib/docker/overlay2/c8b9f4ad647fad4090665c6ee6d63af998265ba008756f6dd24563245043d091/diff/usr/local/bin/elastalert
$ sudo file ./var/lib/docker/overlay2/c8b9f4ad647fad4090665c6ee6d63af998265ba008756f6dd24563245043d091/diff/usr/local/bin/elastalert
./var/lib/docker/overlay2/c8b9f4ad647fad4090665c6ee6d63af998265ba008756f6dd24563245043d091/diff/usr/local/bin/elastalert: Python script, ASCII text executable
```

Comment: Add output of `type elastalert` to your question (no comment).

Comment: try `sudo find -type f -name elastalert 2>null` or sudo find -name elastalert -ls 2>null` . Good luck.

Comment: Also, you said, *`which elastalert` It returns no info.* . No information? Or `which: no elasalert in (...`  Don't make us guess, it's best to always include extact text of error messages :-). Good luck.

Comment: `alias foo=bar`, and you can autocomplete the command "foo", but it'll not display any information when you type `which foo`.

Comment: You can even set autcompletion for a random word that is nothing at all, not even an alias: `complete -W 'bar baz' foo`; `foo` now has `bar` and `baz` as its completions.

Comment: @Cyrus Thank you. added more details above. Which file contains the alias config? It is not in .bashrc and there is no .bash_profile

Comment: @shellter added info above. Not sure if the find -name result has anything to do with this.

Comment: The purpose of `sudo` is to allow non-admin users do administrative tasks. `which` or `find` or even `docker` are not administrative commands, you don't need to use `sudo` to find them. Don't get a habit on using `sudo` when it is not needed!

Comment: @axiac The file is in path not accesible without sudo, I will update that.

Comment: @Cyrus I found the alias /etc/bash.bashrc. Thank you! If you want to write up an answer, I am happy to take it.

Answer (score 3):

I can't give you a specific answer but you may find clues in the bash infotext sections 8.6, 8.7 and 8.8.

In section 8.8 it is ilustrated that scripts that aid completion can be installed separatly from programs which would explain why you get a completion without the said program being in your PATH.